# How to change contents of listbox based off of combobox selection?

Tags: c#

I have a WFA that I use to restore databases on the fly.  Right now I have a list box that displays all of my backups in the directory, but it also contains folders I want access to.  Here is the code for the list box:

```
private void PopulateListBox()
{
    try
    {
        var dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup");
        var files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.bak");

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The application could not find the directory to populate the List Box.");
    }
}
```

Currently I have a combo box set up to display the different folders in Backups:

```
private void PopulateComboBox()
{
    string[] directory = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup");

    foreach (string folder in directory)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(folder);
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is change the contents of the list box when I click on a different directory from the combo box.  I have a method created to achieve what I am trying to do but I'm not sure how to code it.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      listbox1.Clear()
      //rest of the code would go here     
}
```

How can I display the contents of each directory in the list box based off of what selection I have in the combo box?

Comment: Make that folder and extension into global vars, so your SelectedIndexChanged function can combine the base path with the SelectedValue of the combo box, and fetch the files from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm more of a WPF guy, but I'm pretty sure it works the same way here.

You want to handle one of the

> "SelectionChanged" events (SelectedIndexChanged, SelectedValueChanged,
> or SelectionChangeCommitted)

and in the handler you put code to check what item is selected in the combobox and re-populate the listbox based on that selection.

Comment: I marked your solution as the answer and added what I did below, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

a) Make your populateListBox function accept a parameter "dinfo"

```
private void PopulateListBox(string dname)
{
  try
  {
    listBox1.Clear();
    var dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\" + dname); //combine base folder with the folder from combobox
    var files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.bak");

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The application could not find the directory to populate the List Box.");
}
```

}

b) In your selectedindexchanged method, pass the selected value from the combobox into the PopulateListBox function:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PopulateListBox(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
}
```

Comment: I'm close with this, but I had to make some changes.  In the populateListBox function the strings had to become vars and right now it can't resolve symbol 'GetFiles'.  I also had to add .ToString() in PopulateListBox method.

Comment: @BowerdotJson sorry just realised my mistake - corrected now. Based on your solution below you might need to make a special case for "backup" since it's the base folder itself, not a subfolder. But I think hard-coding the base folder once is better than your version of putting it in 3 times. Also in yours you'd have to write more code if the list of folders changes, and I think mine has better encapsulation - things to do with the listbox are within the listbox function, not partly within the combobox event.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I will come back to this again if I need to, currently I am the only one who uses this application so if I need to make changes I will definitely come back to this solution.  Thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming up with my own solution based off of Yushatak's response.  I created a global string variable pointing to the backups folder (this is the default directory when the app starts), created a collection in the properties of the combo box UI, removed the combo box function I created (as it's no longer needed), then used a series of If statements inside the SelectionIndexChanged method to handle which folder I want access to.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Backup")
    {
        string backup = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup";
        PopulateListBox(backup);
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Backups 2")
    {
        string backup = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Backups 2";
        PopulateListBox(backup);
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Backups 3")
    {
        string backup = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Backups 3";
        PopulateListBox(backup);
    }
}
```